# I need an alternative to mitmproxy for python

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, mitmproxy

I have a project and I need to create an HTTP packet interceptor in python as a proxy, but I can not use mitmproxy because it only works from the cli command and not from an internal library. I have an application and I can not tell people to run mitmproxy because that's what the app should do internally. I'm currently using a fork to launch mitmproxy from bash, but it gives me a lot of trouble creating this functionality for other operating systems.

For this reason, someone knows some way to intercept traffic as a proxy that does not depend on a command outside python ?.

Answer (score 1):

mitmproxy can be load inside your python code.

```
from mitmproxy import proxy, options
from mitmproxy.tools.dump import DumpMaster
from mitmproxy.addons import core


class AddHeader:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 0

    def response(self, flow):
        self.num = self.num + 1
        print(self.num)
        flow.response.headers["count"] = str(self.num)


addons = [
    AddHeader()
]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    opts = options.Options(listen_host='127.0.0.1', listen_port=8080)
    pconf = proxy.config.ProxyConfig(opts)

    m = DumpMaster(None)
    m.server = proxy.server.ProxyServer(pconf)
    print(m.addons)
    m.addons.add(addons)
    # m.addons.add(core.Core())

    try:
        m.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        m.shutdown()
```

This code is taken from the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/3306).